# Can't understand "puts" keyword in Ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know ruby language. I was reading a very interesting article which contain a following 2 line ruby code which i need to understand.

```
(0..0xFFFFFFFFFF).each do |i|
     puts "#{"%010x" % i}"
end
```

By googling, i get the 1st line. But i am not able to understand 2nd line. Can someone please explain its meaning?

Answer (score 7):

`puts "#{"%010x" % i}"` has actually two parts - string interpolation (which G.B tells you about), and string format using [`%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-25):

> Format—Uses str as a format specification, and returns the result of
>   applying it to arg. If the format specification contains more than one
>   substitution, then arg must be an Array or Hash containing the values
>   to be substituted. See `Kernel::sprintf` for details of the format
>   string.
>
> ```
> "%05d" % 123                              #=> "00123"
> "%-5s: %08x" % [ "ID", self.object_id ]   #=> "ID   : 200e14d6"
> "foo = %{foo}" % { :foo => 'bar' }        #=> "foo = bar"
> ```

So `"%010x" % i` formats the integer in hex format (`x`) with at least 10 digits (`10`), padding with zeros (the leading `0`):

```
"%010x" % 150000
# => "00000249f0"
```

Actually

```
puts "#{"%010x" % i}"
```

is exactly the same as

```
puts "%010x" % i
```

since the interpolation simply puts the resulting value (a string) within a string....

Answer (score 4):

Puts key word is used to print the data on the console. 
for example

```
puts "writing data to console"
```

above line will print exact line to the console `"writing data to console"`

```
@a = "this is a string"

puts @a
```

this will print `"this is a test string"`

```
puts "My variable a contains #{@a}"
```

this will print `"My variable a contains this is a string"` and this merging technique is called string interpolation.

this first argument in `puts "#{"%010x" % i}"` specifies the format and second represents the value.

and for your exact question and further details see [this link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-25)

Answer (score 0):

it's string interpolation and `sprintf`

documents:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf

http://batsov.com/articles/2013/06/27/the-elements-of-style-in-ruby-number-2-favor-sprintf-format-over-string-number-percent/

`"%010x" % i` is same as `sprintf("%010x", i)`

Answer (score 0):

```
puts "#{"%010x" % i}"
```

This line print the content. and if you want o interpolated the string please used single quote inside the double quote. like this "#{'%010x' % i }"

and %x means convert integer into hexadecimal and %010x means make it 10 place value means if out is 0 then make it like this 0000000000.

Answer (score 0):

**Print**

[`puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-puts) is the equivalent of [`echo` in PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_echo.asp) and `printf` in C

When included in either a command-line app, or as part of a larger application, it basically allows you to output the text you assign to the method:

```
puts "#{"%010x" % i}"
```

This will basically print the contents of `"#{"%010x" % i}"` on the screen - the content of which means that `ruby` will output the calculaton of what's inside the curly braces (which has been explained in another answer)